# Downloadable link doesn't appear in email confirmation

Tags: bundled-product, downloadable, order-confirmation

**The Issue**

I have a bundled product with a downloadable product as a bundled item.   After purchase, I see the downloadable product in the order confirmation but the link DOES NOT exist to download the downloadable product.

**Troubleshooting**

**1.** I get the download link in the order confirmation when I purchase the downloadable product ONLY.

**2.** I also get the download link in the order confirmation when I purchase a single product AND the downloadable product.

**3.** I DO NOT get the download link in the order confirmation when I purchase the bundled product with the downloaded product as a bundled item.

Can someone tell me why?